# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack python

Tags: python

I have got an existing menu that gives you options `L` or `D`. `L` should load the contents of a file and `D` should display it.

```
if option == "l" or option == "L":
    with open("packages.txt") as infp:
        for line in infp:
         line = line.rstrip()
         name,adult,child= line.split(',')

if option == "d" or option == "D":
    print ((name)," - ",(adult)," / ",(child))
```

However, when I try to run this I get the error:

> name,adult,child= line.split(',')
>   ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Why do I get this error?

Comment: FYI: You could also say `option.upper() == 'L'` and make your code slightly easier to read and to maintain/upgrade.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This means that there is a line in `packages.txt` that, when you strip whitespace and split on commas, doesn't give exactly three pieces. In fact, it seems that it gives only 1 piece ("need more than 1 value to unpack"), which suggests that there's a line with no commas at all.

Perhaps there are blank or comment lines in `packages.txt`?

You may need your code to be smarter about parsing the contents of the file.

Comment: Ok that worked, but now for print ((name)," - ",(adult)," / ",(child)) it it saying that the variable "name" is not defined?

Comment: Why would you expect `name` to be defined there? It only gets set when option `L` is taken. Have you done an L before the D that causes that second block to be used?

Answer (score 3):

This error is occurring at

```
name,adult,child= line.split(',')
```

When you assign three variables on the left it is assuming you have a 3-tuple on the right. In this example, it appears `line` has no comma hence `line.split(',')` results in a list with only one string, thus the error "more than **1** value to unpack".

Comment: So what do you suggest i should do?

Comment: Split into cases that condition on the value of `line.split(',')`, particularly the length of the output. If you assume the file will also have three elements, you need to figure out why this line doesn't.

Comment: i fixed it, but now for print ((name)," - ",(adult)," / ",(child)) it it saying that the variable "name" is not defined?

Comment: Yes. The variable `name` will only be set `if option == "l" or option == "L"` as you specify. In the other case, `option == "d" or option == "D"`, so `name` will not be in `globals()` and you'll get a `NameError` when you try to use it. If you set name elsewhere you'd then get a name error with `adult` and then with `child`.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it all! now it is displaying one line of the .txt file. I want to make it so it will display multible lines. is there a way to do that?

Comment: the .txt file looks like this:
vincent,29,129
johannes,20,900
and so on
It is now only displaying:vincent - 29 / 129
I would like it to check how many lines the file has and display it like above

Comment: The code you have described above alone won't display anything. We need to know where `option` is being set and how this interacts with the rest of your program. If you'd like to print every line, the place to do it would be when you loop through the contents of the file via `for line in infp:`.

Comment: Just look at the code on top of the page. it will strip the 3 words in between the commas. and if you hit D it will display the first line only.
I want it to loop until it runs out of lines to read

Answer (score 2):

`line.split(',')` returns a tuple. You then *un-pack* that tuple by writing:

```
name,adult,child= line.split(',')
```

If the tuple does not have exactly three elements then the un-packing fails. In your case the error message states that you have only one element. So, `line.split(',')` is clearly returning a tuple with only one element. And that means that `line` has no commas.

Probably this means that your input data is not what you expect it to be. You require that `line` is a string containing three comma separated values but there is a line in your input data that does not meet that requirement.

Comment: Fewer or more than three elements. You are bound to exactly three elements here.

Comment: Well, you have to work out why this is happening. We can't know why. All we can do is tell you that your input data is not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work around that without adding extra lines and checks, one solution is to change your split to the following:

```
name, adult, child, garbage = (line+',,,').split(',', maxsplit=3)
```

This will silently ignore the missing values, and the variables will be empty. Meaning, the values for `name`, `adult` and `child` will be filled if they are there, and will be empty it the original file doesn't have them. For all intents and purposes, ignore the variable `garbage`.