# Snakefile ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: snakemake, snakeyaml

I am running in snakefile on cluster using this default config:

```
"__default__":
    "account"   : "myAccount"
    "queue"     : "myQueue"
    "nCPUs"     : "16"
    "memory"    : 20000
    "resources" : "\"select[mem>20000] rusage[mem=20000] span[hosts=1]\""
    "name"      : "JOBNAME.{rule}.{wildcards}"
    "output"    : "{rule}.{wildcards}.out"
    "error"     : "{rule}.{wildcards}.err"
    "time"      : "24:00:00"
```

It runs ok for some rules, but it raise this error for one of the rules.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/conda3_64/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 537, in snakemake
    report=report)
  File "home/conda3_64/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 653, in execute
    success = scheduler.schedule()
  File "home/conda3_64/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 286, in schedule
    self.run(job)
  File "home/conda3_64/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 302, in run
    error_callback=self._error)
  File "home/conda3_64/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 638, in run
    jobscript = self.get_jobscript(job)
  File "home/conda3_64/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 496, in get_jobscript
    cluster=self.cluster_wildcards(job))
  File "home/conda3_64/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 556, in cluster_wildcards
    return Wildcards(fromdict=self.cluster_params(job))
  File "home/conda3_64/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 547, in cluster_params
    cluster.update(self.cluster_config.get(job.name, dict()))
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

This is how I run the snakemake;

```
snakemake  -j 20 --cluster-config ./config.yaml --cluster "qsub -A {cluster.account}  -l walltime={cluster.time} -q {cluster.queue} -l nodes=1:ppn={cluster.nCPUs},mem={cluster.memory}" -p
```

If I run it without a cluster `snakemake` only it will run normally.

similar error is here [ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391963/valueerror-need-more-than-1-value-to-unpack-python) but I could not relate.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it right now but based on the error I suspect the issue seems to be with your `JOBNAME` placeholder not being explicitly specified in call to qsub.

Adding `-N some_name` to your `qsub` arguments should resolve it.

Comment: Could be, but the snakefile contains let's say 10  rules . why it only fails with one of them?

Comment: Could be? Can you not test it? To get help on why it fails with a specific rule you should provide the Snakefile or at least which rules fail/succeed as the issue might be with your  rule or wildcard names.  In addition, you can remove  either `JOBNAME` or `{rule}` or `{wildcards}` and see if it fails or not depending on composition of `"name" : JOBNAME.{rule}.{wildcards}`.  Specifying `JOBNAME`  in the qsub command could remove the possibility that your `JOBNAME` gets some clashing node id value.

Comment: Maybe you misinterpret "Could be" It means that I agree that this is the issue, and for sure I am running it but it will take sometime beside I already removed `{wildcards} and {rule}`  still it gave the error. feedback will be given forsure after run.  Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.  I thought you meant *could be* as in *I cannot test it so we will not now*.  I assumed you did not use localrules but another reason why some rules would run correctly is if you had localrules, as these would not be affected by the qsub related issues.

Comment: Thanks again, So if I run the snakrmake with  ` "JOBNAME.{rule}.{wildcards}"` it will write the stderr to snakejob.rulename.wildcardname.e/o.  If I ass `-N foo` it will write to foo.e/o and I will lose the info about the rule in filename. anyway I used what you suggested but it ended the same way with the given error.  thanks